# How can I do arithmetics with user inputs?

Tags: ruby

This is my code trying to calculate the coumpoung interest

```
def coumpoundinterest
 print "Enter the current balance: "
 current_balance = gets
 print "Enter the interest rate: "
 interest_rate = gets
 _year = 2012
 i = 0
 while i < 5 do

  current_balance = current_balance + current_balance * interest_rate
  puts "The balance in year " + (_year + i).to_s + " is $" + current_balance.to_s

  i = i + 1  
 end
end
```

This is the line where I'm getting all the troubles

```
current_balance = current_balance + current_balance * interest_rate
```

If I keep the code the way it is, I get an error that string cannot be forced into FixNum. If I add .to_i after interest_rate, then I get the line multiply several times. How can I deal with arithmetics in ruby?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gets` will return a string with `\n`. Your `current_balance` and `interest_rate` variables are strings like `"11\n"` `"0.05\n"`. So if you only use `interest_rate.to_i`. The operator `*` between a string and a fixnum will repeat the string several times according to the fixnum. Try to convert them into float both.

```
current_balance = gets.to_f
interest_rate = gets.to_f
...
current_balance *= (1+interest_rate)
```

Comment: Using `to_i` will get rid of decimal values. `"0.05\n".to_i => 0`. `to_f` should be used instead.

Comment: @oldergod That's right. I just followed the question's method. It's better use `to_f`.

Comment: @halfelf, makes sense. I'm still trying to think in ruby now (not in C#). Not easy. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Richard77 That's ok. `irb` is a good tool to try any ruby code and see the evaluation of each expression. And run any ruby code with `ruby -r debug` will works like gdb.

Answer (score 0):

I am a new Ruby programmer also and had trouble with data types at first.  A very useful troubleshooting tool is `obj.inspect` to figure out exactly what data types your variables are.

so if you add `current_balance.inspect` after you get the user value you can easily see the return value is "5\n" which is a string object.  Since Ruby strings have their own definitions of the basic operators (+ - * /) which aren't what you'd expect you'll need to use one of the to_* operators (namely `to_f` as already mentioned) to convert it to an object which you can use math operators on.

Hope this helps!